# getElementById using a looping variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I want to fetch a String from my DB and put it into my paragraphs:

```
<p id="q_1"></p>
<p id="q_2"></p>
```

This here works fine:

```
$.get("bewertung/get/1", function (data) {
      document.getElementById("q_1").innerHTML = data[0].question;
})
```

This here doesnt work. Why and how to solve this?

```
for( var j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
    $.get("bewertung/get/"+j+"", function (data){
         document.getElementById("q_"+j+"").innerHTML = data[0].question;
    })
}
//data[0].question is the field in the DB
```

Comment: will you please provifr return data also ?

Comment: you check for `data[0].question` outside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by the fact that when you receive a response from the server(or do any other asynchronous operation loop will be done and `j` variable will be having value `6`. To prevent this you need to create closure for asynchronous operations that is being used in for loops. Note that I've used `setTimeout` instead of AJAX.

```js
for( var j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
    (function(k) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           document.getElementById("q_" + k).innerHTML = 'data';
        });
    })(j);
}
```

```html
<p id="q_1"></p>
<p id="q_2"></p>
<p id="q_3"></p>
<p id="q_4"></p>
<p id="q_5"></p>
```

Comment: Just beat me to it, mon.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer if you know more information about this.

Comment: But why take out the AJAX?  Seems critical

Comment: @XavierJ ajax isn't required to demonstrate the problem/solution.

Comment: @KevinB is right, this applies to all asynchronous operations, also most of JS sandboxes doesn't allow to make network requests(haven't tried in this one though)

Comment: This works! Thank you very much for your answer. As he said: note that ajax has to be put instead of setTimeout